# Точки К, F, Z, M — рёбра прямых AB, DG, PS, TY(,) соответственно

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> Точки К, F, Z, M — рёбра прямых AB, DG, PS, TY(,) соответственно.

Comment: Всё смешалось в доме... Рёбра прямых с точками-рёбрами. Запятая спасёт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужна:

*Точки К, F, Z, M — рёбра прямых AB, DG, PS, TY соответственно*.

Это слово помогает избежать повторение одного и того же (то есть: *Точка К — ребро прямой AB, точка F — ребро прямой DG...*) и помогает сопоставить одно с другим по их номеру в однородном ряду. Так что это обстоятельсьво, а не вводное слово.